# Out of memory NODE.JS can't be solved

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory, exe

I'm trying to to run an executable in a node.js application. When I call the executable with its parameters from the command line everything is ok.

However when I call it from the application like this :

```
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;

function f() {
    exec('code.exe', [some_arguments], function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err);                     
    });
}
```

I get an OutOfMemoryException, which I couldn't solve, even by calling this way :

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 .\app.js
```

I know for sure the process cannot take 8Go of memory, it takes at most a hundred Ko.

Thanks.